# How to create a table and enter result recursively for multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, filesystems, directory-structure

I have a many `.txt` file in a folder1 inside folder2 inside folder3. All folders have many subfolders but the main thing is there are 3 folder hierarchy and then `txt` files in last subfolder. Now I do have python code to run on txt files and get a result which is either one or two outputs for each file. I want to create a table/dataframe/csv file where for a row in the table has columns 'folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3'. name of .txt file and the results from the python code all in the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, haven't tested but you will know what to do.

```
init_dir='D:\\Users\\AChauh11\\PycharmProjects\\untitled1'
dict = {}
def walk(init_dir):
    list = []
    for file in os.listdir(init_dir+'\\'+init_dir):
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            walk(init_dir+'\\'+file)
        else:
            list.append(file)
            dict[init_dir]=list
    return dict
```

This will return a dictionary which you can use to create table in pandas or something like that.

Comment: I modified according but couldn't make it work. Main thing is it wouldn't go inside second folder only return list of files and folders in the first folder.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't tested earlier. Edited solution is tested and works fine. I had foget to pass <init_dir+'\\'+> in os.listdir function.